# Count the number of rows returned by an Accumulo batch scanner

Tags: counting, accumulo

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to count the number of rows returned by a batch scanner in Accumulo without having to manually iterate over all rows returned.

What I have at the moment is something like this

```
Connector connector = // Created a new connector
BatchScanner bsc = connector.createBatchScanner(tableName, Authorizations.EMPTY, numThreads);
/*
... applying filters
*/

Iterator<Map.Entry<Key, Value>> e = bsc.iterator();
long cnt = 0;

while(e.hasNext()) {
     cnt++;
}

return cnt;
```

I am iterating over every row returned by the batch scanner and counting each row that I encounter. What I would like to know is if there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In general ([What is the best way to get the count/length/size of an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720195/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-count-length-size-of-an-iterator)) you won't be able to do this any faster, as your filter could be anything and thus somewhere you're going to have to do some counting.

There are other ways ([Maintain statistics across rows in accumulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268152/maintain-statistics-across-rows-in-accumulo?rq=1)) that you can go about keeping track of the counts, but they might introduce new headaches for you.

Comment: Would it be possible to distribute this task? Maybe feed the iterator to a Spark streaming job or a map-reduce job that could then do the counting?

Comment: You could probably create your own combiner iterator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048613/does-accumulo-support-aggregation and then sum on the client side. At least at that point you're distributing the computation across the cluster and you're reducing the amount of data that is traversing the network.